# Text-overflow is not working and layout is breaking with flex in bootstrap4

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

I'm new to `flexbox` modal in bootstrap4. As per my requirement i need to show truncated text `text-ellipsis` in the nested flex. But unable to show.

Please find my code below and suggest me.
https://jsfiddle.net/trzd3xu1/1/

Answer (score 0):

Please refer this https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/text/#text-wrapping-and-overflow link. Ellipsis can only work with given width. Applying width to your code too will serve the purpose. "https://jsfiddle.net/trzd3xu1/38/" Updated fiddle link

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>IVR</title>
    <meta name="description" content="IVR">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

    <div class="wrapper d-flex flex-column">
        <header class="d-flex justify-content-center">Header</header>
        <main class="d-flex flex-row">
            <div class="sideNav">
                <ul>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                    <li>side link1</li>
                </ul>

            </div>
            <div class="rightContent">

                <div class="inside d-flex flex-row align-items-stretch">
                    <div class="column-1">leftMenu</div>
                    <div class="column-2">
                        <div class="text-truncate" style="width:4rem;">Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</div>

                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </main>
        <footer class="d-flex justify-content-center">Footer</footer>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can we do without adding width?

Comment: You can try using "max-width". Updated fiddle at "https://jsfiddle.net/trzd3xu1/44/"

Comment: What do you want to show here. Problem still there.

Comment: In ideal scenarios, max-width does help solving the ellipsis problem. But you are using flex-grow:1, so the best solution to my knowledge is width only.

Comment: Show the result if you can. It would be great help to me

Answer (score 0):

Hope this could help you:
You should add `style="width:4rem;"`
If this was you requirement than this should be solution:
https://jsfiddle.net/besartm/kLtznj54/

Comment: Please check @Charu Maheshwari comments. It has to be work without adding width

Comment: This solution is without width:  I named a class with **"flex-child"** and on _css_ file for this class added `overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis; ` .Here is the code: [https://jsfiddle.net/besartm/uj7s2ntb/](https://jsfiddle.net/besartm/uj7s2ntb/)

Comment: You just removed the white-space. Thats why text has wrapped here. This is not what im looking. It should be in single row with ellipsis without using width

Comment: Than there is no way without width or you should specify width for parent element.

Comment: please check this and comment https://jsfiddle.net/hyvs3jz9/5/. This layout has no width.

Comment: Your requirements little bit confused

Comment: Actually list of items will come one bye one in the right section. I have to restrict for single row of each item. On mouseover we will display full content in tooltip/popover box. I hope it clears your confusion